# Why this angularjs example doesn't work on plunker?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In this angular document: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts, there is an example about `Directives`.

> ### Directives
>
> A directive is a behavior or DOM transformation which is triggered by the presence of a custom attribute, element name, or a class name. A directive allows you to extend the HTML vocabulary in a declarative fashion. Following is an example which enables data-binding for the contenteditable in HTML.

It provides two live demo, one for plunker, another for jsfiddle.

- plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nsAUafYFA1tHPo52TWUm?p=preview
- jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rnL84/

Why the jsfiddle one works well but the plunker one doesn't work? They have exactly the same code, and there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plunker has `ng-app` instead of `ng-app='directive'` in the **index.html**.

The module (named **directive** in this example) defined in the **script.js** javascript file needs to be specified in the [ng-app](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp) for it to pick up the contenteditable directive:

`angular.module('directive', [])...`

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eZhDz8hIPjM6sjcnAOhz?p=preview) for a working version.

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a tiny difference, I will report an issue for angular team

Comment: @Freewind what kind of issue you would like to report? This is how ngApp works: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

Comment: site issue. The live plunker demo they provided is missing the `directive` on the tag `<html>`

Comment: I don't think the link (http://plnkr.co/edit/eZhDz8hIPjM6sjcnAOhz?p=preview) is working.  At least not on my PC.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It appears to be working for me still in Chrome make sure you click into the "Edit Me" up top (and not the one next to `model =`).

Answer (score 5):

Replace the script provided by Plunker with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```